# Slow read performance with SAMBA

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

I'm experiencing slow read on my samba shares.  Slow speed mean around 4MB/s on windows (1G wired) and about 25MB/s on OSX (wifi).  Write speeds are around 112MB/s which saturate my 1G nic. OSX (wifi) to Windows (1G) is about 50-60MB/s.

The NAS i'm building is a 16G ram, XEON CPU, have 2 SSD in mirror (mdadm) and 2 WD red 4TB in ZFS mirror.  Currently running ubuntu 16.04 and samba 4.3.11.

When i do a local copy from and to SSD i'm getting those results which look fine to me.
`x@nas:/vms$ sudo dd if=./xxx.mp4 of=/sol/movies/testoutput bs=100k count=1k
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.860855 s, 122 MB/s
x@nas:/vms$ sudo dd if=/sol/movies/xxx.mp4 of=/vms/outputtest bs=100k count=1k
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 0.545534 s, 192 MB/s`

Samba config is as follow (no noticeable changes except when i use sendfile, CPU usage skyrocket).
`socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
  ;use sendfile = yes
  ;write cache size = 2097152
  min receivefile size = 16384
  getwd cache = true
  write raw = yes
  read raw = yes`

At this point i'm running out of ideas so i'm open to suggestions.

Thank you

Sol

Answer (score 2):

Check https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/speed.html

We got some improvment using

```
socket options = TCP_NODELAY
```

Comment: Hello Andres, thank you for your answer but i'm already using that socket options.  I'll try removing the other options just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I meet exactly the same problem, solved by two steps.

1. Make sure the samba.conf with option "aio read size = 0"
2. Fix the windows AutoTuningLevel, https://www.omelsoft.com/fix-slow-internet-windows-10-creators-update/